# Finding products by Tags (Prestashop)

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm doing some modifications in the way that customers explore products in Prestashop 1.6. So, I'd like to know if is there a function that works similar to the getProducts() function but gets products from a defined tag (or tags)?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked to product class and I couldn`t find any similar function. You can get product tags, all tags, add tags, del and etc..

But you could write an additional functio, yes? In ps_product_tag table you have: id_product and id_tag so:

1) Find id_tag by product name from ps_tag table
2) Get all products ID from ps_product_tag table where product has assigned ID TAG

Thats it. And also you should do it by overiding Product class. Now you have an array with products id. So now you can use cycle and catch all infformation from products or whatever: `$product = new Product($id_product);`

Comment: Yeah, neither do I... So I've implemented a custom function in override/Tag class.

Thanks manl for your help!